# How to do Calculations On Multiple Form Fields - angular2+

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-directive, angular-dynamic-components

I am working on reactive forms of angular where I have a requirement in the forms as below

Lets say I have 4 input fields.

```
<input type="text" formControlName="a1">
<input type="text" formControlName="a2">
<input type="text" formControlName="a3" value={{a1+a2}}>
<input type="text" formControlName="a4" value={{a1*a2}}>
```

here value is based on formula which may have any arithmetic expression example : (a1*a2)/a3

This form is dynamic data is coming from an api for example

```
const formData = [
  {
    id: "a1",
    type: 'text',
    value: '',
    formula: '',
  },
  {
    id: "a2",
    type: 'text',
    value: '',
    formula: '',
  },
  {
    id: "a3",
    type: 'text',
    value: '',
    formula: 'a1+a2',
  },
  {
    id: "a1",
    type: 'text',
    value: '',
    formula: 'a1*a2',
  },
];
```

please help me with this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwyIv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the `valueChanges` Observable to track changes in the desired inputs and use `setValue` to change the value of other inputs after each change. You should probably also change the input type to `number` to avoid worrying about converting strings to numbers.

Using a formula written as a string is an enitrely different problem. I think you should use `String.replaceAll` to apply the values to the formula and `eval` to calculate the result.

Working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zuy1ed

Code sample:

```
calculateResult(formValue: any, formulaName: "formula1" | "formula2") {
    let formula = this[formulaName];
    Object.keys(formValue).forEach(
        variable => (formula = formula.replaceAll(variable, formValue[variable]))
    );
    return eval(formula);
}

setupRecalculation() {
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
        value.a3 = this.calculateResult(value, "formula1");
        value.a4 = this.calculateResult(value, "formula2");
        this.form.controls.a3.setValue(value.a3, { emitEvent: false });
        this.form.controls.a4.setValue(value.a4, { emitEvent: false });
    });
}
```

---

**Warning:** By default, using `setValue` on a form control triggers the `valueChanges` event. To avoid an infinite loop, use `{ emitEvent: false }` in the second argument of [FormControl.setValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#setvalue)

**Warning2:** The API response you posted in your question seems to be vulnerable to a circular dependency of the variables (for example, a3 depending on a4, which depends on a2, which depends on a3 etc.). There should be a rule which ensures this is avoided: for example, a variable should depend only on the variables which come before it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Wojciech  this helped me but what I am looking  for is how to handle if the formula comes dynamically

Comment: @TNaveen I expanded my answer to handle this and updated the jsfiddle demo.

Answer (score 0):

If values are fix, maybe you can try like this :

```html
<!-- Better to use type="number" -->

<input type="number" formControlName="a1" (change)="calculate()">
<input type="number" formControlName="a2" (change)="calculate()">
<input type="number" formControlName="a3">
<input type="number" formControlName="a4">
```

```js
calculate(): void {
  const { a1, a2 } = this.form.value;

  this.form.get('a3').setValue(a1 + a2);
  this.form.get('a4').setValue(a1 * a2);
}
```